# vuetify select placeholder color

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to change placeholder text color of vuetify select box. My attempt is as below.

```
<v-select
  :items="items"
   placeholder="place"
   dense>
</v-select>

.v-text-field--placeholder {
   color: green !important;
 }
```

But it will not change the placeholder text color. Where I was get wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `::placeholder` selector:

```css
.v-text-field input::placeholder {
    color: green;
}
```